# How do you return to the windows 10 trivia splash from the login text box?

Tags: windows-10

Sometimes I come back to my computer and by habit hit a button to wake my computer. I briefly see something interesting on the Windows 10 "did you know" callouts on the lock screen but I'm already at my login box. Hitting Escape does not return to the previous screen.

In these situations the best way I've found to see the "did you know" thing again is to log in, and Win-L to re-lock my screen.

Is there a better way to exit the login text box?